# Adding dropdown selection to WP Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, selection, custom-post-type, meta

I'm trying to add a "Price Range" drop-down selection to the meta box within my custom post type. There would be three options: $ / $$ / $$$

Here's what I'm currently using to create the select box:

```
<p>
    <label for="price_range" class="prfx-row-title"><?php _e( 'Price Range', 'prfx-textdomain' )?></label><br/>
    <select type="text" name="price_range" id="website_url" value="<?php if ( isset ( $prfx_stored_meta['price_range'] ) ) echo $prfx_stored_meta['price_range'][0]; ?>" />
        <option>$</option>
        <option>$$</option>
        <option>$$$</option>
    </select>
</p>
```

Here's what I'm current using to save the select box:

```
if( isset( $_POST[ 'price_range' ] ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'price_range', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'price_range' ] ) );
}
```

The selection box shows up fine in WP, but it won't save my selection when I publish the post.

Lastly, here's what I have to display the price range in my page template(s):

```
<!-- DISPLAY PRICE RANGE IF ONE EXISTS -->
<?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price_range', true) ) { ?>
<strong>Price Range: </strong>
<?php $meta_value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'price_range', true ); // Retrieves the stored value from the database
if( !empty( $meta_value ) ) { // Checks and displays the retrieved value
echo $meta_value;
}
?>
<?php } ?>
```

I haven't tested this yet, because I haven't been successful in saving my price range meta – but will this work?

Answer (score 0):

You must add a function that is executed when saving the entry

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_custom_meta' );
    function save_custom_meta( ) {
    global $post;
      if( isset( $_POST[ 'price_range' ] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'price_range', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'price_range' ] ) );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I should've mentioned that this was only a snippet of the code I'm using. I do have the function that saves the entry. In fact, it's working on all of my other meta boxes, but those are just input fields. This question's more specific to select fields. I feel like the change will need to be made in one of the snippets I posted above?

Comment: Ah ok, right now I see your options of select, you do not have any value...
<option value="$">$</option>
<option value="$$">$$</option>
<option value="$$$">$$$</option>

Comment: Change the html select code for this...
<?php $price_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price_range', true) ?>
<select type="text" name="price_range" id="website_url" />
    <option value="$"  <?php if ($price_meta  == '$' ) { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?>>$</option>
    <option value="$$"  <?php if ($price_meta  == '$$' ) { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?>>$$</option>
    <option value="$$$"  <?php if ($price_meta  == '$$$' ) { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?>>$$$</option>
</select>

Answer (score 0):

I found where I went wrong:

```
<p>
<label for="meta-select" class="prfx-row-title"><?php _e( 'Example Select Input', 'prfx-textdomain' )?></label>
<select name="meta-select" id="meta-select">
    <option value="select-one" <?php if ( isset ( $prfx_stored_meta['meta-select'] ) ) selected( $prfx_stored_meta['meta-select'][0], 'select-one' ); ?>><?php _e( 'One', 'prfx-textdomain' )?></option>';
    <option value="select-two" <?php if ( isset ( $prfx_stored_meta['meta-select'] ) ) selected( $prfx_stored_meta['meta-select'][0], 'select-two' ); ?>><?php _e( 'Two', 'prfx-textdomain' )?></option>';
</select>
```

And then:

```
if( isset( $_POST[ 'price_range' ] ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'price_range', $_POST[ 'price_range' ] );
}
```